# Spacing between two tiles for good readability?

Tags: mobile-application, cards, information-design, tiles

Are there any studies that having some space between two tiles would improve readability in an app experience?

I've included two wireframes that give an idea of what I mean, which is better spacing between or no spacing between?[image: No Spacing between cards]

[image: Space between card]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's scroll through your first design and stop somewhere in the middle:

[image]

Now, quick: Which button applies to the card? The one above or the one below?

This is the advantage of having a clear division between each section. A space is merely one way to handle that division.

In terms of graphic design, we're talking about creating a relationship between visual elements via the concept of *proximity* (making sure the toolbar is connected to the content block) while maintaining a clear separation between the groups using the specific technique of *[white space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_space_(visual_arts))*.

My favorite example of why these concepts are important is when you're reading a long news article or blog post that is a stream of photos separated by captions but there's no visual cue as to whether the caption applies to the image above or below:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor set...
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...
```

This always takes a bit of cognitive load to figure out at first. I have to figure out the first couple of photos and connect the subject matter of the photo with the text to figure out which I should be focusing on. The simple addition of a bit of white space can make this so much easier to read:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor set...

-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...

-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...

-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...

-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...

-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor set...
```

As for data, I'm sure there's some out there, but this is really a fundamental concept of good visual design. Google 'white space' to find all sorts of information on the topic.

Comment: I like this answer. DA01 you've explored the nittie gritties and exposed the problem accurately. And the illustration was quite self explanatory. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I cannot supply you with the reasons why or usability studies that point to which is better, but by the Google Material Design standards you are supposed to leave a space in between cards.

> **Card margins on mobile**
>
> - Padding from edge of screen to card: 8dp
> - Space between cards: 8dp

[Material Design - Content Blocks](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks)

**Example of cards with margin**

[image]

Comment: This is great, I forgot about this doc from Google. I was hoping some body had conducted a study on this topic and published the data. Looks I'll have to do some A/B testing myself.

Comment: Yah, I assume Google thoroughly tests everything and found this to be the optimal solution but I understand you don't want to blindly follow convention. Perhaps someone will come up with statistics it would surely be interesting to read.